# SharePoint 2013 Autohosted App Feature Activation Issue

Tags: sharepoint-addin

We have created SharePoint 2013 Auto hosted app. In that, we have created near about 50 lists from the solution in visual studio. but when i deploy it, it gives following error:

"there was a problem with activating the app web definition."

What is the reason? any limit for creating lists in Auto hosted app?

Please suggest me...